# How to do element-wise calculation on all element pairs

Tags: matlab, combinations

a=[4 2 5 9]

The I have to write a code using for loop to get the following vector:

[4-2 4-5 4-9 2-5 2-9 5-9]

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: I do not recommend asking us to solve your homework, show some effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    a = [ 4 2 5 9]

    a =

         4     2     5     9

    s = combnk(a, 2)

    s =

         5     9
         2     9
         2     5
         4     9
         4     5
         4     2
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanatory text.

Comment: The function is explained here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/combnk.html

Comment: -1: This solution only works if OP has the Statistics Toolbox installed, which isn't made clear in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a `for` loop:

```
result = tril(bsxfun(@minus,a(:).',a(:)),-1);
ind = tril(reshape(1:numel(result),size(result)),-1);
ind = ind(ind>0);
result = result(ind).'
```

Comment: I love this, because it answers the question and at the same time the OP can't use it (presumably for an intro MATLAB class)!

Comment: Nice solution Luis. The solution I was going to post was a double for loop.He asked for it :)

Comment: @DangKhoa Er... I hadn't thought of that! :-)

Comment: @DangKhoa hilarious :)